# ChartJs - pie chart not showing

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Trying to create a simple pie chart: https://jsfiddle.net/omriman12/px2mbnse/1/

My HTML:

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

My JS:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'pie',
  data: {
    labels: [
      "a",
      "b",
    ],
    datasets: [{
      data: [10, 20],
      backgroundColor: [
        "#DA1A32",
        "#F0FFFF"
      ],
      borderWidth: false,
      borderColor: false
    }]
  },
  options: {
    cutoutPercentage: 0.9
  }
});
```

What am i missing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the chartjs into js fiddle from https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.min.js